# How do I set Chrome as the default browser with a .BAT file?

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe

**Note:** I've already read [Batch - Default Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser), but that's about **getting** the default browser. I want to **set** it.

I'm making a set of batch files to easily set up computers I use (don't worry; they're deep-frozen. I can't do any permanent damage). How can I write one to make Chrome the default browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by running the chrome with *flags*.

- `--make-default-browser`: Makes Chrome default browser.
- `--no-default-browser-check`: Disables the default browser check.

See the [`complete command line list`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) of Chrome.

Comment: for completeness sake: Go to the directory where `chrome.exe` is located, type `cmd` in the address bar (opens `cmd` straight in that directory), type `chrome.exe --make-default-browser`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore... On Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetDefaultBrowser app.

Just add `"path\to\this\program\SetDefaultBrowser.exe" chrome` to your .bat (or run in cmd) to set Chrome as a default browser.

Read more and download it [on author`s website](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/11/10/setdefaultbrowser-set-the-default-browser-per-user-on-windows-10-and-server-2016-build-1607/)